# zsh: separate completion for command names and filenames

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, autocomplete

I do not want filename tab completion to prioritize the start of the file name. For example, given the filenames red_blue.txt and blue_red.txt, I do not want vim red <kbd>tab</kbd> to prioritize red_blue.txt

This can be accomplished by using:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} l:|=* r:|=*'
```

However, this behaviour will also apply to the tab completion of command names, which I do not want. For example, typing nit <kbd>tab</kbd> looking for the command "nitrogen" will also match commands like mkinitcpio, xinit, compinit, and various others.

For commands, I would like the completion to use:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

How can I have zsh tab completion treat command names and filenames differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need to refine the [`zstyle` call](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2) so that it doesn't apply to all completions, but only to file completion. For an ordinary completion, the syntax of the context specifier is `:completion:WIDGET:COMPLETER:COMMAND:ARGUMENT:TAG`.

- `WIDGET` is only set by some special widgets, leave it generic (`*`).
- `COMPLETER` is `complete` for normal completion, and can have other values for tasks such as autocorrection.
- `COMMAND` is typically the name of the command whose arguments are being completed. More precisely, it's the word after `compdef`. Some complex commands change it while completing subcommands. For special places in the shell syntax, it's a [context name between dashes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_002darray_002dvalue_002d_002c-completion-context), such as `-parameter` after a `$` or `-command-` for the first word in a command.
- `ARGUMENT` is typically something like `argument-3` for the third non-option argument or `option--foo-1` for the argument to the option `--foo`.
- `TAG` is used internally by some completion function, often but not always one of the [conventional tag names](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Tags).

In [`zstyle` declarations](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle), more specific declarations take precedence over less specific ones.

- A declaration with more colons (`:`) is more specific than one with fewer colons.
- With an equal number of columns, a declaration is at least as specific than another if each colon-delimited part is at least as specific the corresponding part in the other. For a each part:

  - `*` is more specific than anything else.
  - Anything with wildcards is more specific than a simple string without wildcards.

Thus, in general, to make an exception for command names, just add another `zstyle` declaration that's specifically about commands.

However, there's a twist: `matcher-list` is applied globally, not in the context of completion. In your case, as long as you only want a single matcher, you can use [`matcher`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002c-completion-style) instead.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} l:|=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*' matcher 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, adding the more specific command zstyle declaration is not making any difference. Tab completing a command starting with "nit" is still returning things like mkinitcpio and xinit in the results.

Comment: @BrokeBack Oh, damn, you're right, it doesn't work with `matcher-list`. I don't know why `matcher-list` is applied globally — maybe because it can influence what the extent of the completion context is? It does work with `matcher`, if that's good enough for you.